# Nexus OSS 3.0 repository upgrade

Tags: maven, nexus

Recently Sonatype released new version 3.0 of the Nexus repository. On the first look, the new version has quite a bit new features, and most important for is support for npm modules.

However, I quickly realised that there is no way to migrate our current maven repository to a new version as the structure of the repository has been changed. The migration from the version 2 promised to be available in version 3.1, but I cannot find when it is going to happen. We need support for npm and I wonder if I'll start using 3.0 for npm only would it be possible to somehow merge my npm and maven repositories together once 3.1 released?

Comment: Nexus 2.12/13 has also support for npm. ?

Comment: Actually, I haven't check 2.12 as we currently using 2.11.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus 2 does have support for npm, but npm in Nexus 3 has support for some features that nexus 2 doesn't.   Go ahead and set up Nexus 3 for npm now, when 3.1 is out you'll be able to migrate your existing Nexus 2 repositories into the Nexus 3 instance.